# 06502. 00000 - "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling, stored-functions, ora-06512

Hi I  have one task to solve. I wrote this code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function hr_funct_task4(p_emp_id number)
  return varchar
  as
    v_emp_last_name varchar2(25);
    v_count         number;
    no_emp_id       exception;
    null_emp_id     exception;
  begin

    if p_emp_id is null
    then
      raise no_emp_id;
    else
      select count(*)
        into v_count
          from jobs j
            inner join  employees e
            on e.job_id = j.job_id
        where j.min_salary > 10000
          and e.employee_id = p_emp_id;

      if v_count <> 0
      then
        select e.last_name
          into v_emp_last_name
          from jobs j
            inner join  employees e
              on e.job_id = j.job_id
          where j.min_salary > 10000
            and e.employee_id = p_emp_id;
      else
        v_emp_last_name := 'No emp_id has salsry > 10000';
      end if;
    end if;

    return v_emp_last_name;

  exception
    when no_emp_id then raise_application_error(-20001, 'No emp found! Please, input another emp_id.');
    when null_emp_id then raise_application_error(-20001, 'Input emp_id is null. Please, input not null value.');
  end;
```

call function:

```
begin
  for i in
  (
    select hr_funct_task4(e.employee_id) as last_name
      from employees e
  )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i.last_name);
  end loop;
end;
```

and I received the correct values but also an error 06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s", ORA-06512: on line 4.

Can you please advise me what i am doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Normally there should be an error stack showing the line number. Are you running this from SQL Developer? My guess would be `v_emp_last_name varchar2(25)` is not big enough. It would be safer to declare it as `employees.last_name%type`.

Comment: @Wiliam - yes, I am using sql developer. I tried your advise, but i still receive the same error

Comment: @Wiliam - it shows me ORA-06512: on line 4.

Comment: Try to convert `return varchar` to `return employees.last_name%type` too.

Comment: This error code can be found in old [Oracle's 9i documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e4100.htm#1656): *An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable declared NUMBER(2).* You need to check this case throughout your data flow (which variable's/column's type is on each step and which values are coming into them)

Comment: Are you getting the correct values and an error message **at the same time**? I don't believe that for a second. And if you are sometimes getting the correct values, and sometimes you get an error, you should explain that better. What is different between those two outcomes? When do you get the correct results, and when do you get an error?

Comment: HI @Kristina, were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You declared

```
v_emp_last_name varchar2(25);
```

and later modified it to

```
v_emp_last_name employees.last_name%type;
```

(I presume that `last_name` column isn't larger than 25 characters, is it?)

---

Then, this is what you do:

```
 else
    v_emp_last_name := 'No emp_id has salsry > 10000';
```

Guess what?

```
SQL> select length('No emp_id has salsry > 10000') from dual;

LENGTH('NOEMP_IDHASSALSRY>10000')
---------------------------------
                               28         --> 28 won't fit into 25

SQL>
```